# Advanced Custom Fields + Gallery Field - Show First Image from the Gallery

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I’m trying to show only one image from my gallery field as a thumbnail and when the viewer clicks it a fancybox slideshow pops up.

This is what I have so far:

```
<?php 
    $images = get_field('gallery'); 
    $image_1 = $images[0]; 
    ?>    

    <img src="<?php echo $image_1; ?>" />
```

But the HTML shows this…

```
<img src="Array">
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed the code to this;

```
        <?php 
        $images = get_field('gallery'); 
        $image_1 = $images[0]; 
        ?>    

        <img src="<?php echo $image_1[url]; ?>" />
```

Comment: pretty sure you mean <img src="<?php echo $image_1['url']; ?>" /> you missed the quotation marks around url

Comment: Can you also use
<?php echo $images[0]['url'];?>
<?php echo $images[0]['link'];?>

Comment: It's worth mentioning this only works when the field return value is set to array!

Answer (score 5):

You said you changed the code, but did it help? 
If it did you should mark your answer as "Accepted", so the question can be closed.

If not, then try this, assuming you're using the field as an Image Object (chosen when you create the Image Field):

```
<?php 
$images = get_field('gallery'); // get gallery
$image  = $images[0]; // get first image in the gallery [1] for second, [2] for third, and so on.

if( $image ) : // only show the image if it exists ?> 
    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Remember the ' or " around the ['value']